# Interpolation technique used in numpy

Tags: interpolation, python, interpolation-theory

What is the technique used by the `numpy` `interp()` function?

So using the following points

```
import numpy as np

x = [4.5]
xp = [4, 5, 4, 3]
yp = [2, 4, 6, 5]

result = np.interp(x, xp, yp)

print(result) #result = 5.0
```

When I find the interpolation of `x` the value is `4.5`

But if my points are these 3 `xp = [4, 5, 4]` e `yp = [2, 4, 6]` the value will be `6`

```
import numpy as np

x = [4.5]
xp = [4, 5, 4]
yp = [2, 4, 6]

result = np.interp(x, xp, yp)

print(result) #result = 6.0
```

Comment: Have you read [the source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1456-L1594)?

Comment: (See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72090856).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `xp` array is not strictly increasing. In fact, you even have a repeated value with different corresponding `fp` values! In this case,  the behavior is undefined.

From [the `numpy.interp` documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

> xp: 1-D sequence of floats
>
> The x-coordinates of the data points, must be increasing if argument period is not specified.